# R - fails to format a date column

Tags: r, date-format

I have this dataframe:

```
            date  NO2
2 01/11/16 00:00 56.8
3 01/11/16 00:15 52.3
4 01/11/16 00:30 49.6
5 01/11/16 00:45 55.5
6 01/11/16 01:00   48
7 01/11/16 01:15   45
```

I want to cover the date format to, e.g:

```
2016-01-11 00:00
```

Here is my code:

```
# Convert chr to POSIXct, format for openair.
DF$date <- as.POSIXct(DF$date)
# Make sure that date values are POSIXct, format.
str(anonSpeciesDF)

'data.frame':   14497 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date: POSIXct, format: "1-11-16 00:00:00" ...
 $ NO2 : Factor w/ 1093 levels "[\xb5g/m3]","10",..: 635 590 553 622 537 507 493 463 446 438 ...

# Format the date
DF$date <- format(DF$date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
> View(DF)
```

Result:

```
           date  NO2
2 1-11-16 00:00 56.8
3 1-11-16 00:15 52.3
4 1-11-16 00:30 49.6
5 1-11-16 00:45 55.5
6 1-11-16 01:00   48
7 1-11-16 01:15   45
```

Any ideas why? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try supplying a format string to `as.POSIXct()`:

`DF$date <- as.POSIXct(DF$date, format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")`

Comment: You've supplied a format string to `format()`, not `as.POSIXct()`. You need to tell `as.POSIXct()` what the format of the date it's converting is.